# Errors declaring static const vector in .h file and errors in definitions in .cpp file

Tags: c++, vector, header, implementation

I am simply trying to add some static constant vectors to my date class. Compiler errors given below.
Here is my Date.h file.

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>

class Date {
   private:
      int month;
      int day;
      int year;
      static const std::vector<std::string> monthNames(13);
      static const std::vector<int> daysInMonths(13);
   public:
      Date();
      Date(int month, int day, int year);
}
```

Now my Date.cpp file

```
#include "Date.h"
#include <vector>
#include <string>

const std::vector<std::string> Date::monthNames(13) {"","January","February","March","April","May",
      "June","July","August","September","October","November","December"};
const std::vector<int> Date::daysInMonths(13) {0,31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31};

Date::Date() : month(1), day(1), year(1900){
}

Date::Date(int month, int day, int year) : month(month), day(day), year(year) {
}
```

My g++ compiler gives me errors I cannot decipher for my declaration of my vectors in the .h file and for the definitions I made in the .cpp file. I cannot get the errors to format well in here. Can someone please show me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What are you trying to do with the `(13)` after your variable names?

Comment: trying to size the vector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the `(13)` after the declarations/definitions of your two `std::vector` objects; in fact, you ***cannot*** have them. In the header, you only need to declare the vectors; in your source file, the initializer lists will tell the compiler what those vectors should contain.

*Explanation: Although you can have a statement like `const std::vector<int> dinMon(13)` as "free-standing" code (it will construct the said vector with 13 elements), you cannot do this in the **declaration** of a static class member: this is, after all, only a declaration. So, just the plain vector type - and then the definition (in Data.cpp) has to match, so you can't have the `(13)` there, either.*

Also, you are missing a `;` after the declaration of your `Date` class (that is, after the closing curly brace in your header file).

Date.h:

```
class Date {
private:
    int month;
    int day;
    int year;
    static const std::vector<std::string> monthNames;
    static const std::vector<int> daysInMonths;
public:
    Date();
    Date(int month, int day, int year);
}; // You forgot the semicolon here!
```

Date.cpp:

```
#include "Date.h"
// #include <vector> // Don't need to re-include these, as they are already ...
// #include <string> // ... included by "Date.h"
const std::vector<std::string> Date::monthNames {
    "", "January", "February", "March", "April", "May",
    "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"
};
const std::vector<int> Date::daysInMonths { 0, 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31 };

Date::Date() : month(1), day(1), year(1900) {
}

Date::Date(int month, int day, int year) : month(month), day(day), year(year) {
}
```